# Como puedo deshabilitar un un asp:DropDownList con un asp:CheckBox?

Tags: javascript, html, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy intentando deshabilitar el DropDownList con un CheckBox, de esta manera tengo el Drop

```
<div class="div__format col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTIPO_OBLIGADO" SkinID="cmbGeneralNormal"</asp:DropDownList>
 <label for="ddlTIPO_OBLIGADO" id="lblTIPO_OPERACION" class="form__label_ddl">Tipo de Obligado*   </label>
</div>
```

Este sería mi check

```
<div class="div__format col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xl-2" style="max-width:1%;  margin-left:25px;">
     <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkObligadoSolidario" />  
</div>
```

Pero al momento de cargar la pagina me salta la funcion y no reconoce el ctl00_cphCuerpo_chkObligadoSolidario que le he puesto

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            $("#ctl00_cphCuerpo_chkObligadoSolidario").click(function () {
                debugger;
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $("#<%= ddlTIPO_OBLIGADO.ClientID %>").prop("disabled", false);
                } else {
                    $("#<%= ddlTIPO_OBLIGADO.ClientID %>").prop("disabled", true);
                }
            });
});
```

Como podria solucionarlo o cual seria mi error?

Intente realizarlo de la forma en la que mencione, pero no me funciona